# Can Google index a website with a minified HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, performance, minify

I have made a bootstrap website, the html has almost 400kb, which I think is slow on mobile devices. I want to minify it by using this tool http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/.

- Can Google index properly a website with a mini HTML and CSS?
- Does this matter when Google chose the rank of the site?
- Do you think 400kb is too much?
- Do you think that the website work kine on mobile devices?
- Does size of the HTML influence only the loading speed or the overall performance of the website?
- The address is [www.o-p-a-l.eu](http://www.o-p-a-l.eu) .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about seo and too broad

Comment: You're asking 5 different questions here.

Comment: Yep, 5 questions in 1, isn't that brilliant? i bet no one ever thought about that ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is will be inexed, as this minifier only removes white-spacing and extra unnecessarily added lines, but please notice that your site almost doesn't have any text, it's a pure image site, you need to have a bit more content for google to index something.

Comment: Hmm, text would be a problem, most of the text is in modals, and i dont think that Google can read that. Is it possible to make a hidden page with text?

Comment: If Google detected this it would penalize your site